# Why we need a free graded R-module in the assumption of Thm.22.37 on pg.511 in "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Here is the theorem:

> [image]

But I do not understand why we need a free graded R-module in the assumption, could anyone help me in answering this, please?

Comment: Did you prove the theorem? Maybe include some notes so that we know better what you don't understand.

Comment: Does the book contain a proof?

Comment: I had a proof given to me by my professor but he did not mention any usage for **free** or **graded** we just used the idea of a double dual and the natural embedding map @Tyrone

Comment: @Randall No, the book does not contain any proof.

Comment: So this is Problem 22.39 in the book. How far have you got in completing it?

Comment: My professor discussed nearly all parts of it but I am not fully convinced by his solution this is why I am asking many questions about this problem. You can check my last question here if you want. It is also on a part of it. @Tyrone

Comment: I also got an idea to prove this theorem by the universal coefficient theorem. Maybe e will use that it is **free** and **graded** in that way of solution. I do not know. If you can show me the proof using universal coefficient theorem I would love that and I would be very thankful and gratitude for that. @Tyrone

Comment: I think the idea is to be able to prove it using the methods and tools given in the book. Why don't you try to solve it as advised in problem 22.39? If you get stuck you should ask a specific question rather than asking for a solution to the whole exercise without evening attempting it yourself.

Comment: My main question is when is free and graded used in the proof ..... I do not need the whole proof (I already have one proof but by a different method) @Tyrone

Comment: When you say 'used in the proof', you have not given us a proof to check.

Comment: :)) @Tyrone okay I will try by myself and add it to the body of the question, But I will ask for your check. Ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}P^2$, and $R=\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $H_2(X;R)=0$ but $H^2(X;R)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Thus the first conclusion of the theorem fails.

If you plug this example into the proof of the theorem, the proof must fail at some step.  This will necessarily be a step that is valid when you add the assumption that one of those modules is free graded, but not valid without the assumption.

Comment: Does it fail because $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} $ is not a free module?

Comment: I am sorry for this trivial question ..... but how did you calculate the homology of $X$ with coefficients in $R.$ Can you specify a book explaining this clearly, please?

Comment: Essentially yes, though to be precise, it fails because neither $\tilde{H}_*(X;R)$ nor $\tilde{H}^*(X;R)$ are free graded modules, as they each contain a summand isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ contains torsion, so cannot be a summand of a free module.  The reason to be careful is that in general modules can be non-free, but occur as summands of free modules.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is constructed by taking a point, gluing in both ends of an edge to that point, to obtain a circle and finally gluing in a disk whose boundary goes twice round the circle.  Thus its resolution is: $$\mathbb{Z}\stackrel 2\to \mathbb{Z}\stackrel 0\to\mathbb{Z}$$ A good reference is example 2.42 in http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf